# How to unite two vectors effectively by reference?

Tags: c++, vector, reference, move

In case of two vectors, both containing already allocated data: 
Considering the vector only contains primitives, 
what is the most effective way to concatenate one after the other without copying anything?

In this particular example the vectors would both contain lots of data, possibly millions of numbers. Giving the vectors to a function by reference would aim as optimization, so it would not be required to copy the data from each vector.

Is that really worth it runtime wise ? According [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552481/which-is-faster-pass-by-reference-vs-pass-by-value-c) Question, it might not.

Two possible solutions are using [std::reference_wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)-s or pointers, what is the most effective way for it?

The possible solution would be:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

using std::vector;
using std::reference_wrapper;
using std::for_each;

void a_function(vector<int>& a, vector<int>& b){
    vector<reference_wrapper<int>> united;
    united.reserve(a.size() + b.size());
    united.insert(united.begin(),a.begin(),a.end());
    united.insert(united.end(),b.begin(),b.end());
    // ..use united..
    for_each(united.begin(),united.end(),[&](int& common_vector){
        ++common_vector;
    });
}

int main(){
    vector<int> a(0);
    vector<int> b(0);
    a.push_back(0);
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(3);
    for_each(a.begin(),a.end(),[&](int& common_vector){std::cout << common_vector << "; ";});

    b.push_back(4);
    b.push_back(5);
    b.push_back(6);
    b.push_back(7);
    for_each(b.begin(),b.end(),[&](int& common_vector){std::cout << common_vector << "; ";});
    std::cout << std::endl << "#################################################################" << std::endl;
    a_function(a,b);
    for_each(a.begin(),a.end(),[&](int& common_vector){std::cout << common_vector << "; ";});
    for_each(b.begin(),b.end(),[&](int& common_vector){std::cout << common_vector << "; ";});
}
```

Comment: There is no way. You have to copy something.

Comment: What is your end goal?  Do you just need to iterate over both container but you don't want to write two loops?

Comment: Copying around `int`s is cheaper than creating/using `reference_wrapper`s. We don't know whether the elements the vector are larger than an `int` in your case, but the correct answer could depend on that. Could you amend the question in that regard?

Comment: Your vector of `reference_wrapper`s will occupy just as much memory as a vector of `int`s, and will probably be slower to construct and access. How exactly would you define "effective" in your case? Without knowing that, we cannot give a solution.

Comment: Original error was: that I was mixing const references with non-const references, and was trying to handle both within one vector using reference_wrapper. It gave error messages so scary I was afraid to read out oud out of fear of summoning a demon. Upon constructing the example program it worked flawlessly, but I decided to post the question anyway, with its main focus being performance in the end.

Comment: @Max Langhof Updated the question with the intended type of the vector elements! Thanks for poitning it out!

Comment: If you have huge amounts of data you which are costly to copy you can write your own container which internally is a vector of vectors. You simply push whole vectors, which are moved, and provide the API of a container to the users (especially iterators, which iterate across the internal vector boundaries).