# Does C++ std::vector passed as function argument decay into a reference or copy?

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

When I pass a std::vector into a C++ function, like so:

```
void myFunc(std::vector<int> myVec)
{
// do something
}
```

Does the vector myVec get copied or is in reality only a pointer passed? I'm asking from optimization perspective; should I always explicitly pass a pointer to the vector or is there a difference in speed? Assume that I only want to read the data in the function, not manipulate the vector itself.

Comment: It is a copy in your example. Also use const if you don't manipulate data. A reference is always prefered.

Comment: *Assume that I only want to read the data in the function* Then you pass a `const &`. Passing things by pointer is generally not what you want.

Comment: It is called **pass by value**. This is explained in any beginner [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Also see [Why pass by const reference instead of by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582797/why-pass-by-const-reference-instead-of-by-value). And [Which is faster? Pass by reference vs pass by value C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552481/which-is-faster-pass-by-reference-vs-pass-by-value-c)

Comment: put meaning and correctness first. The reason to pass by value or by reference is mainly because you either need a copy or not a copy. Performance follows from writing code that expresses what it should do rather than something else, because your compiler knows how to emit efficient output